# If Earth's rotational speed is zero at the North Pole, why do stars still have apparent motion?

Tags: star, night-sky, apparent-motion

The apparent motion of stars (and other objects) results from Earth's spin on its axis, hence the rising and setting of some stars, and the circumpolar nature of others.

If the ground is not moving beneath your feet, then there shouldn't be any apparent motion from the North Pole. But my Stellarium app, when set to 90°N or 90°S, still shows all stars moving in circles around the North Celestial Pole.

What am I missing?

Comment: Angular speed (which Is relevant) is not zero ať the pole.

Comment: If the ground *is* moving beneath your feet then you're not standing still.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing, that is what happens. The rotation is not null at the pole,only the circumference velocity.

Think of a spinner. It rotates everywhere as a fixed body. The only difference is how fast any part rotates around the rotational axis. But every part takes the same time for one revolution